# I need a JavaScript or HTML solution to embedding only a specific container class from a remote url

Tags: javascript, class, embed, external, containers

Ok, so I'm going to try to clarify my question:

On a website (unfortunately I can't reveal the site until it launches) A complex voting system updates constantly and produces a band name.

The name is then placed in a span in simple text form like this:

< span class voted >  Croupier < /span >

I need to pull just the word Croupier from the span so I can display the text as a heading...

No other spans on the site have this id

The text changes all the time so I need something in my site that references or pulls the text from this span in real time (or nearly)

Like for example when you embed or iframe, when the site changes, the frame changes.

I only need the span info though, not the entire site.

Is there a way to frame or embed - or use Javascript - to display only the contents of this specific span class?

Thanks for your patience!!

Comment: is the "other website" on the same domain as the page you want to include it on? ("domain" being the first part of the URL, eg: `www.google.com` and `www.yahoo.com` are separate domains)

Comment: What you want has crossdomain issues. You can get any page from JS using AJAX, but you cannot get things from sites with different protocol or domain or port. You will need to use backend to achieve such a thing, or if you own both domains, you can do CORS technique https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP_access_control

Comment: So, on the remote site, [some process] causes a particular span to update with the "current top-voted" group. This process makes the span update constantly. Your goal is to always have access (from a completely different site) to the key piece of information: "What is the current top-voted group?". To this end, you are looking for a way to pull out *just* the span containing this information, from the remote site.    Is this an accurate summary?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible on the client-side due to the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). It can be achieved on the server-side through several methods, such as scraping the site via [cURL](http://curl.haxx.se/) and pulling the relevant data out with some basic string parsing, or by using a higher-level tool such as [WWW::Mechanize](http://search.cpan.org/dist/WWW-Mechanize/) for relatively static (on the client-side) content, or [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) for more-dynamic content, such as elements which are created via Javascript.

If there is in fact an agreement between the external site and your own, you may be able to use modern techniques to work-around the Same Origin Policy, such as [Cross-Origin Resource Sharing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-Origin_Resource_Sharing).

Comment: Ok so, can I iFrame the entire site into a document on my domain and then pull the specific class from the intermediary document? Its not my site, its an affiliate site that I would like to only use the content that's relevant to me and have it auto update... How do I use this CORS method? I can have my affiliate put a script on their site if need be...

Comment: if you can have the affiliate put a script on their site, why not have them provide access to *just* the data that you need, rather than trying to pull a specific element out of a larger page?

Comment: Because it constantly changes - many times a day... It depends on how people vote on their site - also new most popular artists can come from an enormous ever growing list - way to much to manage that way. Just to complicate things further its critical that it be as near to real time as possible. These musicians are paying for their chance to be recognized and marketed.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to ask. If you have more information which you believe would help me or others answer your question, edit your question to add the relevant information.